# IBM-Cloud: Schedule a Deployment

Tags: ibm-cloud, devops-services

we are trying to `schedule a deploy`, something like `every sunday at 4 am, do deploy, even if nothing has changed`, but reading official docs of IBM Cloud: [here](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/ContinuousDelivery/pipeline_composites.html#compositepipeline_modify_dp), the docs does not match with tools in console:

Docs:

[image]

Real:

[image]

So, the question is: **how can we schedule a deployment?**

**Update:**

We only see this options:

[image]

after clicking "Config Stage" we see:

[image]

There are 2 options available:

1. Execute on previous stage finished
2. Manually excecute stage

**Update 2:**

[image]

**Update 3:**

[image]

Comment: Could you add details on your region and what you are doing?

Comment: i have updated question to add details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs you refer to are describing a capability provided by the (currently experimental) Composite Pipeline feature. If you want to try this, go to the toolchains page (https://console.bluemix.net/devops) and click on the "Pipelines" item, then click on the "Learn More" link on the "New experimental feature!"

[image]

Note that this feature *is* experimental, and is not available in all regions. In addition we may change how we deliver the capabilities Composite Pipeline current provides over time.

Comment: i did it, but i was not able to complete the steps, please see Update 2 of question.

Comment: Can you try creating a toolchain in US South and seeing whether it works for you there? (I'm just trying to understand whether it's a problem in that region, with your account, or something else).

Comment: sure, i will try again, 1 min please.

Comment: Ok. I'll ask for one more piece of information: What is the exact URL in the browser when you are on the pipelines page and seeing the error? For example, for me it looks like: 

https://console.bluemix.net/devops/pipelines/dashboard?env_id=ibm:yp:us-south

If we can't diagnose the problem after this, you'll have to enter a support ticket and get a real developer to help you. :-)

Comment: thank you verymuch, problem/error was fixed this night, today i was able to create composite pipeline

Comment: your answer is the solution of this question, since the steps are right. thank you

Comment: just another thing please, how can we schedule a periodical deployment? something like "every sunday". (please see update 3) we have to add manually each deployment schedule

Comment: I'd actually like to have a longer conversation with you about the feature you're looking for. The simplest way to do this is probably to go to the developerWorks forums and ask your question here: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/topics/devops-services/